# Visualization of mutations in (part of) viral genome - existing tools?

Tags: vcf, visualization, covid-19, software-recommendation, sars-cov-2

I'm trying to visualize mutations in SARS-CoV-2 sequences, somewhat like it's done on outbreak.info:
[image: An overview of mutations in the B.1.617.2 lineage, shown as dots labeled with amino acids on a horizontal bar divided by genes.]

but for individual sequences, probably on the base of the vcf files generated by the [ARTIC pipeline](https://github.com/artic-network/fieldbioinformatics). A pipeline focused on virus nanopore output.

The ready-made tools I've found for visualization of mutations so far were specifically tailored to human sequences and/or for visualizing aggregated data for multiple genomes, or were web tools, which can't be used for medical data due to confidentiality.

Is there any existing offline tool that

- is Linux-based
- can be integrated into an automated pipeline
- is tailored towards viral genomes or is "organism-agnostic"
- is based on comparing an individual sequence to a reference sequence
- shows the sequence as "blocks" of genes with the mutations highlighted
- (ideally plays well with MultiQC for integration into an existing report, but that's a nice-to-have)

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `lolliplots` from the [trackViewer R package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/trackViewer/inst/doc/trackViewer.html); it can do VCF-based visualization *and* is flexible enough I can feed it data from other sources (I wound up parsing Nextclade mutation calls for the amino acids since I had these anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your update, this really useful. The Vignette package I do recognise, it does look really cool